# Store and retrieve Boolean Object to a MySql database

Tags: java, mysql

This is my first question here, but before asking to you I have searched all around the Internet without solution.

I want to store Java Objects in a MySql database and to do so I'm using the data type BLOB for all the objects. The MySql table is:

```
CREATE TABLE settaggi_variabili_pc (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PC1 BLOB, PC2 BLOB, PC3 BLOB, PC4 BLOB, PC5 BLOB, PC6 BLOB, PC7 BLOB, PC8 BLOB, PC9 BLOB, PC10 BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

In there I have to store Java objects like Color, Font and Boolean:

```
prpdStmnt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE settaggi_variabili_pc SET PC1=?, PC2=?, PC3=?, PC4=?, PC5=?, PC6=?, PC7=?, PC8=?, PC9=?, PC10=? WHERE id=?");
for (int i = 0; i < vDati.size(); i++)
{   
    Variabile_variabili_pc vpc = (Variabile_variabili_pc) vDati.get(i);
    Object o = null;
    if (vpc.getOggetto() instanceof Color)
        o = (Color) vpc.getOggetto();
    else if (vpc.getOggetto() instanceof Font)
        o = (Font) vpc.getOggetto();
    else if (vpc.getOggetto() instanceof JSwitchButton)
        o = (Boolean)((JSwitchButton) vpc.getOggetto()).isSelected();

    prpdStmnt.setInt(11, i + 1);
    for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        prpdStmnt.setObject(x, o);  
    }

    prpdStmnt.executeUpdate();
```

The `JSwitchButton` is a custom class that extends AbstractButton.
All this code works right.

My problem is when I try to retrieve the Boolean Object, this is the code:

```
ritorno = db.eseguiQuery("SELECT PC1, descrizione FROM settaggi_variabili_pc");
try
{   
    while(ritorno.next())
    {
        InputStream is = ritorno.getBlob(1).getBinaryStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        o = ois.readObject();

        if (o.getClass().equals(Color.class))
            System.out.println("Object type Color");
        else if (o.getClass().equals(Font.class))
            System.out.println("Object type Font");
        else if (o.getClass().equals(Boolean.class))
            System.out.println("Object type Boolean");
    }
}

catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the `ObjectInputStream` read the Boolean object the code return a `java.io.EOFException` error. This error come becouse the Boolean Object, during the store action, was tranlated to TINYINT value in MySql database and it is not stored as a Boolean Object.

So the question is: how can I store a Boolean object to a BLOB MySql Type and how can I retrieve it to a Boolean object again like I done with Color or Font? Is there a way so I can store the Boolean like an Object and not like a primitive type?

Thank you to all.

Comment: Good well asked for the first time! +1 for that. Although, I don't know your specific requirements for this system of yours, you should know that storing lots of blobs in the database will be an overkill regarding performance. I think you should try to think in a better design.

Comment: My intention is to store the Java Objects, so when I retrieve it I have the Object ready to use in the code. The MySql table is only 11 columns and about 20 rows. All this objects are "properties" to configure clients: when a client start the program, it SELECT all his properties and configures itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as [@Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos) pointed out, what you have is **not** a good structure for storing things in a database.  Even for your application, simple configuration data would better be stored in some sort of flat text format (*i.e* [INI Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) or similar.  If you *really **must*** use a database, you should certainly think about using either an [object oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database) or even an [Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool (such as [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28framework%29)) sitting on-top of MySQL.

Getting down to an actual *answer*, Just change the line `else if (o.getClass().equals(`**Boolean**`.class))` in your code above (note the bold), to use a more appropriate class, such as `Integer` or `Byte` - that way when the TINYINT is returned fro MySQL you will be able to represent it.

As an aside, I think you would benefit from [The StackExchange code review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Your code is **VERY** sloppy, and would certainly benefit from a review.  You can have your code reviewed without changing your database, if you really want.

Comment: I have the EOFException when executing `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);` and not in the `else if.....` line. The problem is that in the InputStream I have only 1 byte.

Comment: @rafee try using whatever type is meant to wrap that datatype.  My guess would be a `Byte`.